# When do you use Get or Be in the passive voice?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

When do you use **get** or **be** in the passive voice?

I have seen both used for passive voice. Sometimes they seem interchangeable and sometimes not. Is there a rule for which one to use?

Examples where both works

> I was paid for my work.
>
> I got paid for my work.

Example where *got* doesn't work

> It is believed to be true.

Answer (score 8):

Regardless of the "formality" or "informality" of its usage, *get* **is** often used instead of *be* in the passive voice.

The principal difference in their usage is that *get* can be used to express actions and change and is only used with *action*, not state, verbs, whereas *be* can  be used both with action and state verbs.

Expressing action,  the passive with *get* makes it possible to differentiate between an action and a state if it is not otherwise clear:

> The living room window was broken. (a state or an action)
>
> The living room window got broken. (an action)

The passive with *be* and the agent mentioned also makes the distinction clear:

> The living room window was broken by the burglar. (action)

Also, *get* is often used in the meanings of "to cause something to happen" and "become":

> I’ll get your jacket cleaned if you like.
>
> Let’s hope she gets better soon.

In addition, the *get passive* is also used in certain set expressions, such as 
"get dressed", "get married", "get lost", etc.

> I took a shower and got dressed.
>
> When did they get married?
>
> Have you ever got lost while travelling?

[(The source.)](http://www.grammaring.com/the-passive-with-get)

Comment: I cannot understand why people don't just answer as you did. Simple and to the point, the main point.

Comment: "I will soon be \ get done with my work"

Answer (score 3):

The get passive can be a useful way of making clear that the meaning of the construction as a whole involves action or event, rather than a state.

Compare:

> They got married.The chair got broken.

with the ambiguous

> They were married.The chair was broken.

The latter examples are ambiguous because they can refer to the process of being married or broken, but also to the state of being married or broken