# Past participle usage in below sentences / passives

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english, passive-voice

I hope all the below form of sentences give ‘Passive’ meanings, am I correct?

1) **be** + *verb3* [i.e. past participle]

> *be prepared*.

2) **being** + *verb3*

> *being processed* (but in continuous form).

3) **getting/get/got** + *verb3*

> *getting married*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely correct! (Apparently that answer is too short: "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 24.") . So I'll try again:

Yes, absolutely correct!  Those are all passive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but all of them have different semantics.

Being + V3 is not grammatical by itself, but you can add copula (to indicate continuous aspect version of be + V3) or use it as gerund. Basically, being + V3 is just a conjugation of be + V3.

For be + V3 vs got + V3, look at this answered question: [When do you use Get or Be in the passive voice?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97506/when-do-you-use-get-or-be-in-the-passive-voice)